# Web API 404 Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am getting 404 Error while calling web api method...

below is my code

Web API Controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    private  HomeDataProvider homeDataProvider = new HomeDataProvider();

    // GET api/<controller>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    //[Authorization]
    public List<User> Test_API(HomeSearch searchParam)
    {
        List<User> Test_User = null;
        try
        {
            Test_User = homeDataProvider.Test_DataProvider(searchParam);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return Test_User;
    }
```

Web API Config

```
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Web API Web.config

```
      <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <roleManager enabled="false" />
    <!--<roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
enabled="true" />-->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</modules>
  <handlers>
   </handlers>

      </system.webServer>

I am using windows 10, vs 2015, iis 10
url i am calling
http://localhost/webapi/home/get
Error: 404, static handler error
```

I searched and tried all options on stackoverflow and other sources but all in vain

Comment: Where is your get method in home controller ? In ur route, there is no action method, then how are u calling a method

Comment: This didn't worked... please provide me solution. ..

Comment: Update your routeTemplate to routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}" in API config file and check

Comment: I tried .. Alex suggested the same ... still 404 error ... static handler

Answer (score 2):

I figured out answer

Actually:
In Web API settings:
i selected : Local iis, localhost/webapi... create virtual directory
so my route was
localhost/webapi/webapi/home/get 
Thanks Alex for help and probable solutions you posted...

Comment: Was jumping in to take a look at the code you posted..Glad you figured it out! The more things you tried, the more it seemed like an IIS setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you either need to add `{action}` to your route template or try calling the endpoint without get in the URL like so:

```
http://localhost/webapi/home
```

Comment: i did below change : still 404 error:
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "API Default",
                    routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

Comment: Can you share how you are trying to call the endpoint? Whether it's JavaScript or something else?

Comment: @NikhilMittal just to check you are calling this URL with the port number the service is running on right? Ex. localhost:44368/webapi/home/get

Comment: Yes sir, the webapi is in localhost:80 .... default web site... i can see the webapi in default web site

Comment: Any other solution to try sir

Comment: Since you are setting up attribute routing in the WebAPI config, can you try adding the attribute [Route("webapi/home/get")] to your web method and see if that works? If it does that would help narrow down the issue

Comment: Another thing to try is debugging this from VS instead of publishing to IIS and seeing if you're able to hit the endpoint that way. If that's the case it may be an issue with your IIS setup

Comment: I added the route and tried with vs as well as publishing. .. still same error... in iis also I verified all settings. .. seems proper... static content and dynamic content is also enabled. Any other option

Comment: If you tell me your email. .. I can mail you code... if that works

Comment: I installed route debugger too... However even thr i m getting file or directory not found error

Answer (score 0):

### Publishing a WebApi on IIS (Windows 10) and localhost

These are just my personal experiences, not a complete guide, but it worked for me.

Publishing in Visual Studio 2017/2019

- Profile Publish method: File System
- Target location points to the directory you want to publish to, i.e. "C:\Develop\MyWebApi\published"

Notice:  If a WebApi works in Visual Studio Debugger, it doesn't mean, that it works in IE too. Therefore you'll have to make additional settings, see below.

IIS itself has to be configured to generally work with WebApis:

- Control Panel/Programs/Programs and Features/Turn Windows features on
  or off/Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Services/Application Development Features/ select everything except CGI.

Configuration IIS Application Pool (Computer Management/Services and Applications/Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager/expand your computer/Application Pools/Add Application Pool...)

- Name: freely selectable, i.e.. "WebApiLocalhost"
- .Net CLR-Version:
  4.0 (don't worry, your WebApi can have a higher level)
- Identity: "LocalSystem"

  Normally recommended: "ApplicationPoolIdentity"(default). This user then must have file-system rights (read and execute) on the WebApi's publishing-directory
   ("C:\Develop\MyWebApi\published" in our example), and on all directories, the WebApi may address later. Possible problem with "ApplicationPoolIdentity" is that it's pseudo-user "IIS AppPool\<pool name>" exists only for the local computer and not for the domain. This can lead to problems when assigning permissions to folders of foreign servers.

  Notice: If you only need rights to local folders and want to use the pseudo-user "IIS AppPool\<pool name>" and your computer is in a domain, you cannot find this user by the default way. You have to select your local computer via the button "Locations..." first.

  For the identity "LocalSystem", the system user "IUSR" must receive the corresponding file system rights.

  A third option is to hardwire the identity to the local user with password. But this has the disadvantage that password changes always have to be trailed here, which is often forgotten.

Leave the other options at defaults.

Configuration WebSite (I tried HTTP only)

- Bindings: HTTP, select a free Port i.e. 8094, no IP Address, no Host
  Name
- Application Pool: your application pool, in our example: WebApiLocalhost
- Physical Path: points to the WebApi's "Publish"-Directory, here "...MyWebApi/published"

Attention:

- %LOCALAPPDATA% in IIS-Webapplications under ApplicationPoolIdentity
  "LocalSystem" points to
  "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\" and not to
  Vc:\Users\\AppData\Local\". That means: If you have additional
  application-files like config.xmls or similar below %LOCALAPPDATA%,
  make sure that they exists in the IUSR's %LOCALAPPDATA% too.

Attention:

- The system user "IUSR" must have read and execute rights to the
  Publish folder of the WebApi (in the example
  "C:\Develop\MyWebApi\published") as well as to all folders used
  within the WebApi application. So possibly on:
  "c:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local..." and
  possibly on external directories.

Attention:

- After client-specific changes, especially in the Javascript
  environment, before a new test, necessarily delete the browser cache
  (Chrome via Ctrl-Shift-Del).

Attention:

- "c:\ Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\" may contain
  outdated versions of application files - I searched for hours.
  Solution: Delete application-specific folders below ...\WebsiteCache\
  regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to me, and solved with unlikely solution:
Just by Enabling Directory Browsing in IIS Website features view.